# ezdxf (Python) generate a technical drawning from an 3D CAD model

Tags: python, pdf, autocad, ezdxf

Got stuck while trying to generate a technical drawing in PDF with [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) from an OBJ model with:

- a front view, a side view and a spatial view
- some annotations if possible
- on horizontal A3 (420 x 297 mm) paper
- manage the scaling if possible

Something like this drawing but then of a teapot, simple and effective:

[image: my perfect technical drawing]

## Very important note

**I do not expect a fully detailed drawing as an answer!** (But if you feel like it I won't stop you). Explanation of basic concepts or some guidance in the right direction I will consider as an answer.

The ezdxf documentation seems to assume some CAD experience but I have absolutely zero! The whole modelspace and paperspace concept is confusing to me. I have no idea what viewports are.

## Minimal Working Example

To get started, get the teapot OBJ model (or any model) and convert it to faces and vertices with [trimesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh):

```py
import io

import requests
import trimesh

obj_raw = requests.get(
    "https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/as3/code/as3/teapot.obj"
).text
mesh_model = trimesh.load(
    file_obj=trimesh.util.wrap_as_stream(obj_raw), file_type="obj"
)
```

With ezdxf I can actually read this model and print it to PDF with the `qsave` method:

```py
from ezdxf.addons.drawing import matplotlib

import ezdxf  # '0.17.2'

doc = ezdxf.new("R2010")

# get the modelspace
modelspace = doc.modelspace()
mesh = modelspace.add_mesh()
with mesh.edit_data() as mesh_data:
    mesh_data.vertices = mesh_model.vertices
    mesh_data.faces = mesh_model.faces

matplotlib.qsave(modelspace, "teapot.pdf")
```

[image: side view of the teapot]

That looks beautiful! Next, we can add a box on the paperspace margins; but I have no idea how to add any viewport to the modelspace so it's completely empty:

```py
psp = doc.layout("Layout1")
psp.page_setup(size=(420, 297), margins=(10, 10, 10, 10), units="mm")
(x0, y0), (x1, y1) = psp.get_paper_limits()
psp.add_line((x0, y0), (x1, y0))
psp.add_line((x1, y0), (x1, y1))
psp.add_line((x1, y1), (x0, y1))
psp.add_line((x0, y1), (x0, y0))
matplotlib.qsave(psp, "teapot_paper.pdf")
```

[image]

if usefull, the `trimesh` object has some helper attributes:

```py
>>> mesh_model.bounds
array([[-3.   ,  0.   , -2.   ],
       [ 3.434,  3.15 ,  2.   ]])
>>> mesh_model.centroid
array([ 4.51110653e-02,  1.33032137e+00, -4.36791498e-06])
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, what you basicly want is a way to manipulate the mesh or the modelspace to show the wanted sections (front-/side-/spatial-view) to be printed on a single output page (for example a pdf file). Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct... also getting a solid model instead of the wires is something I am struggling with